# Look for recommendation on implementing Animation Pane (similar to PowerPoint) in FabricJS / Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, fabricjs

I'm building a design panel using FabricJS and Vue 3.

I have implement some simple animation for the objects.

Now I want to control the sequence (or maybe start time) of object to be animated.

Something similar to PowerPoint animation pane:
[image]

**Would like to look for some idea how to implement this?
Is there any existing library I can refer?**